# what's the difference between ajax.org platform and ajax.org O3?

Tags: javascript, ajax

what's the difference between ajax.org platform and ajax.org O3?

I tried to see this from site, but I didn't understood much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Platform is client side and O3 is server side where *a collection of C++ components are exposed through a JavaScript API*